# AccountShare record not able to query with UserOrGroupId as filter, when rowcause is 'Rule'

Tags: soql, apex-sharing

Tried to query AccountShare record with UserOrGroupId as filter, this works good for all RowCause except 'Rule'.

[image: AccountShare records for an Account]

I tried to filter the above query with UserOrGroupId with RowCause as Owner, its working

[image: RowCause_Owner]
[image: RowCause_Implicit]

Then tried with RowCause as Role, its not showing any records

[image: RowCause_Rule]

But the are showed with RowCause as filter

[image: Without UserOrGroupId as filter]

I need to filter using AccountId and UserOrGroupId for my scenario.
I think the above query are correct. If wrong anybody can correct me.

Comment: What happens if you add AND RowCause = 'Rule' to the query for specific UserOrGroupId?  Also, it might be related to this known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5bQAAS  Are you on a Winter'15 instance?

Comment: It could be the same issue @guy mentioned, I tried the same query in a Winter 15 release and it worked but my sandbox is on an instance where the issue has been fixed.

Comment: @guy Thanks for the response. My instance is Summer 14, yes probably it may be the issue as mentioned in the link. Will try the same once my instance is updated, hope it will work.